# How do you iterate over a JavaScript object's properties like an array?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I don't mean using a for loop using the keys.

For example if you had an array like:

```
var fruitArray = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Coconuts"],
    curFruit   = 0;
```

You could "iterate" over that using buttons, say you've got a prev/next button and all those buttons do is decrement/increment the `curFruit` index.

So if I'm on Bananas, I could get Apples using the prev button using:

```
fruitArray[0] // Apples
```

Where the index was at 1 for Bananas but the prev button drops the index by one.

So with an unknown-length object, and not using a numbered-index, how could you do that?

Say it's like this:

```
var fruitObject = {"Apples":"Red", "Bananas":"Yellow", "Coconuts":"Brown"};
```

I realize you could have set 0, 1, 2 and the fruit name, but just to show that you don't know what the object key/index might be.

So if I'm on Bananas using

```
fruitObject.Bananas // yellow
```

How could I get to Apples using the same decrement idea as the Array?

**My question is not about the for in method**

I don't know why that's not clear, it was literally the first line in my question.

I think I found a solution anyway though it might not be direct/the most effective way to do it where I'll create a temporary local "look up".

To explain:

Here's an object

```
var colorObject = {"red":"apple", "blue":"blueberries", "yellow":"banana"};
```

I don't want to use the for in method to go from left to right complete.

I want to be able to start/keep a current position like I'm at `"blue":"berries"` and I can jump to "red":"apple" without knowing what `"red":"apple"` is

My current solution in mind is, yes, though ironically I would use the for in method but to create a look up array.

Something like

```
var tempArray = [];

for (var key in colorObject) {
  tempArray.push(key);
}
```

Then I can navigate the object starting from anywhere using the increment/decrement method.

`tempArray[1]` would return "blue" and I could go to "red" by doing `tempArray[0]` which is interpreted as

```
colorObject.blue // blueberries
```

**Edit thanks to the editor for making my question more clear**

I did poorly word it so that's on me.

Comment: `Object.keys(obj)`

Comment: @SeinopSys yeah I see that but it's not a sequential 0 to 1, it might not even be numbers, I'm wondering if you have to create a local temporary array with the 0-# sequential order paired with the keys in order of the object.

Comment: @RadLexus it's not a duplicate, that was the first line in my question, I know that's how you could go through an object like that using a for loop but I'm asking about jumping left/right of a current object "index" not doing a for loop.

Comment: Order of object-elements doesn't matter. I'm pretty sure, object `[a,b]` is same as `[b,a]` from JS-standpoint, so if you want to keep a track of its elements order it's probably best to use additional array.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 thanks that's the approach I decided to go with. I wasn't sure if there was a more efficient "official" way to do it. Just as a way to keep track of your progress as you go through an array where you might go in either direction not just sequential.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. [JavaScript object properties do not have a defined order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order), so there is no concept of Y key comes after X key.

[Excerpt from EnumerateObjectProperties section of ECMAScript 2017 Draft (ECMA-262)](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-enumerate-object-properties) (emphasis added):

> The mechanics and **order of enumerating the properties is not specified** but must conform to the rules specified below.

If you were to iterate over the properties of your `fruitObject` object, `"Bananas"` may or may not come before `"Coconuts"`, this behavior simply is not defined by the specification. There does not even appear to be a guarantee the properties will come back in the same order each time you iterate over the properties.

The only way to have a consistent order would be to have an array. Optionally, you could do this by creating an array of the properties via [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```js
var fruitObject = {"Apples":"Red", "Bananas":"Yellow", "Coconuts":"Brown"};

// Get the property keys in an ordered list:
var fruitObjectKeys = Object.keys(fruitObject);

// An array of properties with a consistent order:
fruitObjectKeys.forEach(function(prop) {
    console.log(prop, '=', fruitObject[prop]);
});
```

Note however that the JavaScript engine running the code will decide what the order of the resulting array of properties is if you do it this way.

Comment: I found a solution, I'll just create a temporary look up array to use for the increment/decrement navigation of an unknown object structure but yes, it does use for in but it's not what I was after / already knew that. Ayee... whatever at least you can just create new accounts. Anyway thanks for understand what I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

Objects don't have order, so you can't say that the first element of `fruitObject` is "Apples", the second is "Bananas" and the third is "Cocounts".

You could get the keys as an array with `Object.keys()` and then do something like

```
var keys=Object.keys(fruitObject);
fruitObject[keys[0]];
```

Remember that in JS it's the `obj.key` is the same than `obj["key"]`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a helpful tip.